# Composer not resolving dependency for private repositories

Tags: php, git, composer-php

This question is basically regarding the correctness of `composer.json` and validation of the setup that we have.

1. I have a private composer repository host with [Packages](https://github.com/terramar-labs/packages)
2. I have my PHP codes/packages on gitlab. Again privately hosted.
3. I am setting up a magento project and my Extensions are on gitlab and `packages`.
4. The setup is working perfectly. Except Composer is not resolving dependencies for packages/modules dependant on each other.

**Please note that the root project has the definition of my private repo.**
Following are composer.json(s)

### Root Project

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.1.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.0",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha"

    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2",
        "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "use-include-path": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": "app/code/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },
    {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://magerepos.mycompany.com/"  # my private repo
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

### Package Backend

```
{
    "name": "mycompany/quickview-backend",
    "description": "Backend Module for quickview",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/module-admin-notification": "100.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "MyCompany\\Backend\\": ""
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

### Package Frontend

```
{
    "name": "mycompany/quickview-frontend",
    "description": "Quickview Module Frontend",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "mycompany/quickview-backend": "dev-master"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "MyCompany\\Quickview\\": ""
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://magerepos.mycompany.com/" 
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

The `repositories`, `minimum-stability`, `prefer-stable` nodes I added to composer.json of `Package Frontend` When composer reported an error of not being able to resolve the dependencies.

First I tried as follows:

```
composer require mycompany/quickview-frontend
```

But it never worked I thought may be stability and version can be problem after adding `minimum-stability`

```
composer require mycompany/quickview-frontend:dev-master
```

Still getting same error:
`Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.`

I understand the composer won't resolve the recursive repositories and hence I mentioned it in root composer.json. Still no luck

One more thing all the packages and root project are having only `master` branch

Can you guys help me where I am going wrong ?

Comment: I'm not sure if composer will prompt for credentials on https url's, so have you tried using ssh instead?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Yes it does and credentials are not a problem. just like github's auth.json composer is saving credentials for my gitlab server and things are working well.
For `packages` to clone repos from gitlab we have provided The GITLAB API Access tokens.